# jOOQ - method invoking

Tags: java, sql, methods, invoke, jooq

I have question about invoking method **count()** in following sample jOOQ statement:

```
create.select(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, count())
      .from(AUTHOR)
      .join(BOOK).on(AUTHOR.ID.equal(BOOK.AUTHOR_ID))
      .where(BOOK.LANGUAGE.eq("DE"))
      .and(BOOK.PUBLISHED.gt(date("2008-01-01")))
      .groupBy(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
      .having(count().gt(5))
      .orderBy(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME.asc().nullsFirst())
      .limit(2)
      .offset(1)
      .forUpdate()
      .of(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
```

I have tried to create mechanism like this to invoke method without using object/class reference, but I have given up. Is it really possible to achieve it?

Thanks for help.

**Wicia**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hang in there! :-)

You're citing the very first example from the website. I suggest following the [manual's section about how to read the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/the-manual/) (I know, this sounds like I'm RTFM'ing you. Sorry about that), where you will find a couple of explanations, e.g.

```
// Whenever you see "standalone functions", assume they were static imported 
// from org.jooq.impl.DSL. "DSL" is the entry point of the static query DSL

exists(); max(); min(); val(); inline();
// correspond to DSL.exists(); DSL.max(); DSL.min(); etc...
```

The [tutorial](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/) also shows how to do it, i.e. with static imports:

```
// For convenience, always static import your generated tables and
// jOOQ functions to decrease verbosity:
import static test.generated.Tables.*;
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Note, there's a pending feature request [#3503](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3503) to improve the manual and the website with tooltips, in order to explain these things to new users, which will quickly become common practice once you get a hang of jOOQ.